# Multivariate symbology issue

Tags: symbology

I want to symbolize my map based on two sets of values:

1. Data Type (active mine, abandoned mine, core, other)
2. Lease holder (A, B, C, D)

There are various combinations of the above data. I'm imagining a shape for the data type column (square, circle, triangle, etc.), and colors for the lease holder. So the end product would be a red triangle, a green triangle, red circle, green circle, blue circle, etc., all describing the various combinations.
Any thoughts?

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/454987/88814

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Someone recommended making a few copies of the layer, doing a definition query for each to highlight the specific data and then symbolize accordingly.