# Displaying only labels of points that are visible in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, labeling, visibility

I have a large point layer that I have symbology classified by att field `"Property Type"` then the property type field is further subclassed into `"Class"` (A, B, C for example).

I only want to display the points and labels for the class points I have checked but I have to have the property type master checked to display any of the class subcategories.

See the screenshot below, I want the C class to be the only points and labels visible. I got the `"Apartment Brick"` points invisible by just reducing the point size to zero, but the labels still cloud everything.

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there is no red C point hidden underneath the 224 for example?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an expression in combination with a custom function for this.
The custom function is described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386889/45041

1. Create the custom function
2. use an expression for labeling which checks if the feature is visible:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit1:
Instead of using en empty string for the labels which should not be shown it's probably cleaner to just use the expression for the "Show label" setting as shown below:
[image]